# What is the actual definition of "Render"

Tags: rendering

So, I'm looking to be able to explain what I do on blender, and I know this sounds stupid, but in the definition, I can't find the right definition to incorporate into how I explain blender and making Youtube Intros/Outros.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_(computer_graphics)

Comment: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/introduction.html

Comment: Some synonyms would be building, making, processing.

Answer (score 2):

It will depend a bit on whether you're trying to explain this to a layman, trying to draft a professional description (like for LinkedIn or other professional profile), or just trying to generally understand the technical definition. If you can add this info to your question, it'd be helpful.

That being said...

The [Merriam-Webster definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/render) is actually useful in beginning the description, particularly definitions 4 & 5:

> 4a (1) :  **to cause to be or become** b (1) :  to reproduce or represent by artistic or verbal means :  depict (2) :  to give a performance of (3) :  **to produce a copy or version of** (4) :  to execute the motions of
>
> 5:  **to direct the execution of**

[Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_(computer_graphics)) is a little bit more accessible:

> Rendering is the process of generating an image from a 2D or 3D model (or models in what collectively could be called a scene file) by means of computer programs.

But the most useful description would probably be the one that I (very officially) just came up with:

> Rendering is the process of turning the digital description of a scene, at a particular moment in time, into an image. Rendering is a lot like taking a photograph of a scene that only exists in the computer. Scenes are described in simplified, human-accessible ways, and the computer then uses that description to calculate all of the implied (non-explicit) things to determine the color of each pixel in the entire image.

A very useful analogy in describing this process is telling someone else what to draw. I could write a letter to someone, describing what I wanted them to draw (without using any pictures), and the process of them reading what I wrote and turning it into a picture is almost EXACTLY the same as rendering in Blender (in fact, in the art world, the physical process of putting marks on paper is actually called 'rendering'). In fact, it's so similar that I could even add a tiny drawing of what the bumps on one of the bricks looks like, and that's a LOT like using an image texture in Blender.

The ONLY difference between this and rendering with Blender is that humans can make assumptions, but Blender can't. The letter could say "a double-hung aluminum window with 6 equal panes," and a person would have a very clear idea of what that looks like, but Blender would need a LOT more information.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in English, but in French, the 'render' ('le rendu') is the effect something gives (mainly to the eyes). This is very informal...

That can be applied to many things, but mainly about visual aspects, we say "ça rend bien !" ("it is rendering well!") for instance that can be about setting up some furniture at home, or drawing, or any visual effect... but that can be about sound, music... surely about any of our senses... mmm... wine for instance :). About wine, we can say "the in mouth rendering")

So, this is some subjacent thing which is operating to give an effect... Here about Blender, this is your composition (models, materials, ...) which Blender translates to images.

More technically speaking, surely this is about vertices, normals and shaders... put them all in the box and Blender will do it.

OK... but I clearly prefer "wow... this rendering emotes me !"

So surely, a good render is a scene setup which goes straight to eyes and heart !